# Scala macros example not working on Scala 2.12.6

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I am taking the following code from [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

```
package example.macros
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.collection.mutable.{ListBuffer, Stack}

object Macros {
  def printf(format: String, params: Any*): Unit = macro printf_impl

  def printf_impl(c: Context)(format: c.Expr[String], params: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val Literal(Constant(s_format: String)) = format.tree

    val evals = ListBuffer[ValDef]()
    def precompute(value: Tree, tpe: Type): Ident = {
      val freshName = TermName(c.fresh("eval$"))
      evals += ValDef(Modifiers(), freshName, TypeTree(tpe), value)
      Ident(freshName)
    }

    val paramsStack = Stack[Tree]((params map (_.tree)): _*)
    val refs = s_format.split("(?<=%[\\w%])|(?=%[\\w%])") map {
      case "%d" => precompute(paramsStack.pop, typeOf[Int])
      case "%s" => precompute(paramsStack.pop, typeOf[String])
      case "%%" => Literal(Constant("%"))
      case part => Literal(Constant(part))
    }

    val stats = evals ++ refs.map(ref => reify(print(c.Expr[Any](ref).splice)).tree)
    c.Expr[Unit](Block(stats.toList, Literal(Constant(()))))
  }
}
```

Or as viewed in the IDE:

[image: IDE]

When I try to compile my project in IntelliJ I get this:

[image: compile errors]

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Show your `build.sbt`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue with IntelliJ. I solved it by declaring a dependency on `scala-reflect` (`"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.12.6"`).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from scala 2.11, `scala.reflect.macros.Context` Context have been split into `scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context` and `scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context`

You'll have to import the one you want !

More explanations here : https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html

Comment: They (cala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context and scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context) still don't import in my IDE.